# Has Wonder Woman's lasso of truth ever snapped?

Tags: dc, justice-league, wonder-woman

Is there any canon instance where Princess Diana of Themyscira (aka Wonder Woman)'s "[Lasso of Truth](http://www.comicvine.com/lasso-of-truth/4055-41435/)" has ever snapped? Or is it truly indestructible?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps when it was created the boast meant that it would not be able to be broken by any weak god or strong mortal of the period. I suspect that any of the greater gods such as Zeus, Posidon, Hera, and Hades could break it. Especially since Bizarro managed the feat. His strength should only approximate Superman's full strength, implying that a superstrong mortal such as Superman, Doomsday, perhaps Captain Marvel, and Black Adam all possess the ability to break it. Assuming they could resist the will power attack to stand still once wrapped within it. "Unbreakable" is relative...

Comment: @Thaddeus - It can only be broken where truth itself is in question; Bizarro breaks it because he's the antithesis of truth, Rama-Khan breaks it because Wonderwoman refuses to accept that he's telling the truth. In both cases, the lasso repairs itself immediately afterwards. Superman has tried repeatedly to escape its bonds so clearly strength isn't what's needed...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It has been snapped on several occasions, notably by [Bizarro Superman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bizarro) in "[Batman/Superman/WonderWoman : Trinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman/Superman/Wonder_Woman:_Trinity)"

[image: Bizarro]

and by [Rama Khan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama_Khan) in "[Golden Perfect](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/JLA:_Golden_Perfect)"

[image: Rama Khan]

She also breaks it (deliberately) in the alt-universe story "[Superman : Red Son #2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Red_Son)"

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) I have begun downloading those comics to read up on :D Also, please continue to edit and add more instances as and when they strike you!

Answer (score 12):

The concept of continuity has become increasingly fluid of late with Grant Morrison's Multiversity which deems Earth-10 as, likely, to be the setting of Mark Millar's "Red Son", wherein Wonder Woman is subdued with her own lasso by Batman to serve as bait for the Soviet Superman.  Wonder Woman breaks her bonds (and accordingly causes a shock to her own nature) proving the lasso to not be indestructible... but at considerable cost... only a shell of herself henceforth.

**Incidentally, if enchanted to its limits, the lasso may be very hard to break indeed!**
[image: The JLA move planet Earth using Diana's lasso.]
<sub><sup>[**JLA Vol 1. #75**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/JLA_Vol_1_75)</sup></sub>

Comment: "Batman has already compensated for the stress we're putting on the Earth's surface..." Anyone can be strong enough to redirect a planet, but only Batman can reinforce an entire planets structure!